# Regular expression which gets the last part after a special character

Tags: python, regex

I am new to programming need some help regarding regular expressions.

I have a string like this: `xxxx.yyyy.zzzzz.mystring`

What I need from the above string is `"mystring"`, so I am looking for a regular expression which gives the string after last `.` character and also the string before it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the below code to get the string after the last dot.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "xxxx.yyyy.zzzzz.mystring"
>>> m = re.search(r'(?<=\.)[^.]*$', s)
>>> m
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f9538d62370>
>>> m.group()
'mystring'
>>> s.split('.')[-1]
'mystring'
```

To get the full string which was present before the last dot,

```
>>> m = re.search(r'^.*(?=\.)', s)
>>> m.group()
'xxxx.yyyy.zzzzz'
```

To get the first part (*part before last dot*) and second part (*part after the last dot*) in two separate groups,

```
>>> m = re.search(r'^(.*)\.(.*)$', s)
>>> m.group(1)
'xxxx.yyyy.zzzzz'
>>> m.group(2)
'mystring'
```

**Pattern Explanation:**

- `(?<=\.)` Positive lookbehind asserts that the character proceeds the match must be a dot.
- `[^.]*` Match any character not of dot zero or more times.
- `$` Asserts that we are at the end.

Comment: what if a want the string before it

Comment: you mean the string before last dot.?

Comment: yes i need "xxxx.yyyy.zzzzz"

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve this without regex

```
print "xxxx.yyyy.zzzzz.mystring".split('.')[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 (?!.*\.)(.*)
```

This should so it.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/rX0dM7/4

Comment: Perhaps adding an explanation of your regex would add more value to your answer.

Comment: it uses negative lookahead .says that the string should only be matched if it doesn't satisfy negative lookahead..*\. covers upto the last . So it should match after that.

Comment: What is the difference between `(?!.*\.)(\w+)$` and `\w+$`? Can `\w+` contain periods?

Comment: (?!.*\.)(.*) this should be it actually.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need regex here btw. You can simply use `split`.

```
>>> s = "xxxx.yyyy.zzzzz.mystring"
>>> s.split('.')[-1]
mystring
```

Answer (score 0):

one solution without reg-exp, if you are intressted

```
str = "xxxx.yyyy.zzzzz.mystring"
spl = str.split(".")
print spl[len(spl) - 1]
```